# Trying to replace text string is notepad++ with wildcards

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to replace text in a kicad program using notepad++. I am having trouble using wild cards.

This string I am trying to find is one similar to this...

(fp_text reference J2 (at -8.30084 1.4004 270)

J2 is a wild card, but will not be changed and it can be anywhere from 2 to 5 characters long)

-8.30084 can be any number that I want to change to zero

1.4004 can be any number that I want to change to zero

270 will not change, no matter what the number is.

In the end, I want the string to be

(fp_text reference J2 (at 0 0 270)

Comment: can you put a sample data and your desired output?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried? What exactly is your problem? Do you get errors? If yes, which ones? As it is, your question is too broad to be answered concisely. Please see the "help" link at the top of the page to learn how to ask good questions here.

Answer (score 0):

If in understand correctly you're looking for a regex to match that and replace the first and second (but not the third) number with 0. Without knowing what are valid characters for the token you have as J2 I'll assume that it's any non-space character.

You can reference a [capture group](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) within your replacement string. So you can capture the parts you want to preserve. (In the example below I also capture other unknown parts of the string, but that's not really necessary.

The regex should be something like:

```
(\S)\s\(at ([-+]?\d*\.?\d+) ([-+]?\d*\.?\d+) ([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)\)
```

And your replacement will be something like:

```
\1 (at 0 0 \4)
```